# pointer assignment to const char*[] in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, constants

I'd like to assign a pointer to a const char* array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


const char *keyContainer[2]= {"test", "test2" };
const char *keyPtr = &keyContainer;


int main(void)
{  
   printf("%s\n", keyPtr[0]);     //test
   printf("%s\n", keyPtr[1]);     //test2

   return 0;
}
```

keyPtr contains the address of keyContainer but I can't get access to the content of keyContainer.

Comment: What do you mean you can't? What did you try and what were the results?

Comment: A good place to start would be to declare the pointer correctly.  What you have should give a compile-time error due to incompatible pointer types.

Comment: okay you're right, i should compile the code before posting next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this, you get the warning "Initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]", and that's because `keyContainer` is `char *[2]`, which we will say can be **similar** (not the same !) as `char **`. So you need to use `const char **keyPtr = keyContainer;`.

For example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *keyContainer[2]= {"test", "test2" };
const char **keyPtr = keyContainer;

int main(void)
{
   printf("%s\n", keyPtr[0]);
   printf("%s\n", keyPtr[1]);

   return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I tend to view dynamic array initializations as a bad idea (and a bad addition to the C language).  `keyContainer` should really be static.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but this was to explain why the pointer was badly initialized.

Comment: It would have been better to place `keyContainer` outside of the function (and possibly `keyPtr` as well for simplicity).

Comment: Well, sure but this is just an example, I took his code and put it in a main function. I will edit this.